# how to decode and print json in smart3

Tags: php, smarty

I am new with smarty. I have a key value paired json stored in my mysql table and I want to decode and print it with key without a loop. for example.

```
{
    "A": "100",
    "B": "200",
    "Cart": true
}
```

found decode method

```
*.$json|json_decode:1|print_r.*
```

but how i can echo like in php `$json['A'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
{$myjson = $json|json_decode:true}
```

then

```
{$myjson['A']}
```

OR

```
{$myjson.A}
```